# Bash, how to separate/split values in comma separated form

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have here my script which will extract values from files. My problem is when there will be more than one value (specifically in the number variable),
I don't know how I am going to separate them. I only come up with comma separated form.

```
#!/bin/bash
egrep -l 'NG' /home/archive/* > /home/archive/console.txt
chmod 644 /home/archive/console.txt
while read FILE 
do

        file=$FILE          
        cat $FILE | awk '{gsub("-",RS);print}' > file1.txt
        chmod 644 file1.txt
        cat file1.txt | awk '{gsub("*",RS);print}' > file2.txt
        chmod 644 file2.txt
        date=`sed -n '10p' < file2.txt `
        number=`awk 'BEGIN {FS="*"; i=0; ORS=""}
                  $1=="NG" {a[i++]=$4}


                 END { 
                    if (i>1) {
                        print "" a[0]
                        for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
                            print ","  a[j] 
                            }
                        if (i==1)
                            print "" a[0] ""
                    }'  file1.txt`   

        echo "name: ${file}"
        echo "creation_date: $date"
        echo "number: ${number}"

done <  /home/archive/console.txt
```

And here is the sample file.txt content:

```
ABC*72832*123*782327*1234*SRET     *723825W43*834734*73298 *2014Nov30*STRR*K*2014*WRERFD*0*P*-TREKTKR*FGSRTR*SRET*72382543*20140613*1805*78403698*O*005010-FD*7C*78405492-NG*VL*847*347*23-KDJRFK*6729*124713-7238S*A-6283HD*723H*124714-7120373*A-8723D*Y*2*2*2-
HSSDQW*7E*78405493-NG*VL*847*347*24-RDERE*872*124715-
```

My actual output using above script is this:

> name: file1.txt
>   creation_date: 2014Nov30
>   number: 23,24

On the other hand, my expected output would be this one:

```
    name: file1.txt
    creation_date:2014Nov30
    number:23

    name: file1.txt
    creation_date: 2014Nov30
    number:24
```

It must have the same value for name and creation_date(since they are on the same file) while in the number field, they must be split/disjoined. Is this feasible?

Comment: Use a space as separator and add a for-loop around the 3 echos?

Comment: Whatever it is that you are trying to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is wrong and dangerous**.  If you intend for the file to be world readable, `chmod 644` is probably what you are looking for.  For a directory, 755 is a suitable world-readable mode.

Comment: consider rewriting your program as 1 awk program. While we can't "see" your input, based on your output, it should be much less complicated than what you're doing now. Good luck.

Comment: Can you give an example of some line in `file.txt` please

Comment: @Jidder: Please refer to the content sample. I also make some alterations with my script.

Comment: If my answer didn't help, which parts are not working?

Comment: @triplee:it don't generate an output.

Comment: Updated my answer and also tried to salvage formatting in your question.  Please review for problems with the data file.  For this input, I get the output "347" printed twice both with your script and with mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are needlessly dividing the task into very small snippets.  It will be both easier and simpler to do everything in a single Awk script.

```
#!/bin/bash
egrep -l 'NG' /home/archive/* |
while read -r file   # note -r
do
    awk -v RS='-|\n' -v FS='*' '
        # Assume date is always on first line, please check?
        NR==1 { date=$10 }
        $1=="NG" {x[++i]=$4}
        END {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                printf "name: %s\ncreation_date: %s\nnumber: %i\n",
                    FILENAME, date, x[j]
        }' "$file"
done
```

Notice how the script avoids the use of temporary files by keeping all processing in a single pipeline.

I'm not sure the Awk script is entirely correct; but without knowledge of the file you are processing, there's a lot of guesswork involved.  If you have an actual specification for the input file format, that would help reduce uncertainty.

Comment: Could you not just change RS to `-` instead of using `tr`

Comment: @Jidder Good point.  Although I guess you need `RS='\n|-'` if you want to keep existing newlines as record separators, too.